# Stewart's Theorem on Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Can you prove
$$|z_1|^2\cdot [(1-r)\cdot|z_1 - z_2|] + |z_2|^2\cdot(r\cdot|z_1-z_2|)= |z_1-z_2|\cdot(|(1-r)z_1+rz_2|^2+r\cdot(1-r)\cdot|z_1-z_2|^2) $$

(such that $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$, $0 \leq r \leq 1$)

without constructing a triangle.

---

So far I started solving the LHS and arrived at $$|z_1 - z_2| [|z_1|^2 \cdot(1-r) + |z_2|^2\cdot r]$$ At this point it started to look a little like the RHS.
Not entirely sure if I should proceed by expressing $|z_1|^2$ as $z_1\cdot \bar{z_1}$ and expand further. When I continue this why, I don't know how to arrive at $|(1-r)z_1+rz_2|^2.$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: @GregMartin you're right, shouldve included some of my work. Left it out before mainly because I feel it is incorrect or not the best way to approach the question.

Comment: It seems like a good idea to expand out not only $|z_1|^2 = z_1 \bar z_1$, but also the same expansion with the complicated squares-of-modulus on the right-hand side. Perhaps things will cancel away conveniently.

Comment: just expand the right hand side in terms of $|z_1|^2$ and $|z_2|^2$, and you will see the terms $z_1 \tilde{z}_2$ will cancel out and gives you exactly the expression on the left hand side.